# Why are modules inherited completely in pytorch linear regression constructor?

Tags: python, constructor, pytorch

I've been trying to understand this piece of code here for a bit:

```
    class linearRegression(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputSize, outputSize):
        super(linearRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(inputSize, outputSize)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out
```

why is the initialisation of the torch.nn.Module being inherited completely into this class? how does this help when self.linear is calling functions used for the module straight from torch.nn.linear anyways? Would be awesome if somebody could give an explanation on this!

Comment: Your question is unclear, you should look into OOP on Python to clear some things up.

Comment: While the words chosen are odd, the assumption is correct: `nn.Linear()` is identical to an instance of the class *linearRegression*. Defining a new class like this is redundant and probably used for educational purposes only (without an activation layer it is limited to *outputSize = 1*).